# Как исправить функцию которая возвращает подстроку из переданной строки. (javascript)

Tags: javascript, строки, функции

Есть функция(см. ниже). Как пример, если вызвать console.log (substr('abba', 2, 3)); выдает - baundefined. В чем причина, помогите разобраться.

Функция принимает на вход три параметра:

- Строка.
- Начальный индекс. Значение по умолчанию: 0.
- Длина подстроки. Значение по умолчанию: длина всей строки.

```
const substr = (str, index = 0, strL) => {
  let result = '';
  if (strL > str.length) {
    strL = str.length;
  };
  if (strL < 0) {
    strL = 1;
  };
  if (index < 0) {
    index = 0;
  };
  if (index > strL) {
    return '';
  };
  for(let i = index; i < index+strL; i++){
    result += str[i];
  };
  return result;
  };
```

```
substr('abba', 0, 1);    // => a
substr('abba', 1, 2);    // => bb
substr('abba', -10, 2);  // => ab
substr('abba', -1, 100); // => abba
substr('abba', -1, -1);  // => a
substr('abba', 1, -10);  // => b
substr('abba', 1, 10);   // => bba
substr('abba', 1, 0);    // => ''
substr('abba', 100, 3);  // => ''
```

Comment: "Длина подстроки. Значение по умолчанию: длина всей строки." — это сомнительное понимание. Если строка составляет 3 символа, а начальный индекс будет 2 и вы по умолчанию примете длину подстроки как 3, тогда функци попытается захватить три символа начиная с предпоследнего и выйдет за границы строки. Наверное, подразумевается, что по умолчанию длина подстроки равна остатку от индекса до конца строки?

Comment: Вам нужно эмулировать https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr ?

Comment: Хотя у вас вроде другое поведение с негативным индексом.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Я сильно запутался. Так поставлено условие задачи. И я пытаюсь ее хоть как то решить. for(let i = index; i <= strL; i++) попробовал сделать так. Но тогда если вызвать console.log (substr('abba', 3, 4)); выводит aundefined.

Answer (score 1):

Как @vsemozhebuty писал в коментах, у вас неверные предположения в коде. Вот что-то более-менее похожее на рабочий код, с сохранением вашего подхода:

```js
const substr = ( str, index = 0, strL )=>{

  if( index < 0 || index > str.length - 1 ) throw Error('неверный индекс');
  if( strL < 0 ) throw Error('неверная длина');
  
  if( index + strL > str.length ){
    strL = str.length - index;
  }
  
  let result = '';
  
  for( let i = index; i < index + strL; i++ ){
    result += str[i];
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log( substr('abba',2,3) );

console.log( substr('abba',3,500) );

/* Проверки с ожидаемыми ошибками:

console.log( substr('abba',-1,500) );

console.log( substr('abba',500,3) );

console.log( substr('abba',2,0) );
*/
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Но это не совсем мне подходит. Поскольку функция должна работать и с отрицательными значениями. Я вот правил описание. Там указаны примеры какой должен быть результат. И моя функция с этими примерами справилась. Но если брать другие варианты на подобии той, что я указал в вопросе console.log (substr('abba', 2, 3)) возникают ошибки.

Comment: @Joji я понимаю ваше желание сделать функцию такой как вы говорите, но такое поведение обычно считается ошибочным. Поэтому я сделал выбрасывание ошибок. А ошибочным считается потому, что отрицательный индекс в обычной человеческой логике не корректен. Поэтому придётся лезть в описание функции чтобы найти что будет в таком случае. И очень повышается возможность возникновения скрытой ошибки в общем коде потом. Лучше делать явное логичное поведение, а отрицательные случае обрабатывать вовне.

Comment: И у вас смысл отрицательного индекса всё равно был не тот, что в оригинальной функции substr в js

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь:

```
result += str[i];
```

Сложение `result += str[i];` воспринимается JS как конкатенация строк.
Символ номер которого больше чем `str.length` возвращает `undefined`.
JS пытается сложить строчку и тип `Undefined`, приводит `undefined` к строчке `'undefined'` и записывает его в конец строки `result`.

Вариантов исправления 2.

1. Ввести переменную `max = index+strL` и заранее не дать ей превзойти `str.length`

```
  const max = index + strL
  if( max > str.length ) max = str.length;

  for( let i = index; i < max; i++ ) {
    result += str[i];
  }
```

2. Проверять в цикле и делать `break`, если сумма превысила. Первый вариант лучше, проверок меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Чем вам не угодила стандартная функция `substr` встроенная в `js`?

```js
const substr = ( str, index = 0, strL )=>{

  if( index < 0 || index > str.length - 1 ) throw Error('неверный индекс');
  if( strL < 0 ) throw Error('неверная длина');
  
  if( index + strL > str.length ){
    strL = str.length - index;
  }
  
  let result = '';
  
  for( let i = index; i < index + strL; i++ ){
    result += str[i];
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log( substr('abba',2,3) );
console.log( substr('abba',3,500) );

console.log('abba'.substr(2, 3));
console.log('abba'.substr(3, 500));
```